# how to reinstall R kernel on jupyter notebook

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I used to have R kernel on my jupyter. I removed it then then tried to install again. 
I did:

```
install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()
```

I got the error message below:

```
Error in IRkernel::installspec() : 
  jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127.
```

I have no clue what happened. I googled but found no answer...
Appreciate it if anyone can help me with that. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem.

It seemed that it was caused by the missing of some packages. Notice the information listed during the following step:

```
install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))
```

In my case (just in my case), it showed that
[image]

At first, I didn't pay any attention to this warning and met the same problem as you met. Then I tried to fix it by installing the package and it worked.

I hope this experience will be helpful for you.